# Return patients with no new records in 18 months

Tags: mysql

My query is supposed to look for and extract data for all patients who haven't had an entry for 18 months.

```
oID   Date          Crea
1     2014-09-22    153
1     2012-10-15    365
2     2014-08-02    212
2     2015-02-18    245
3     2016-03-19    438
```

I extract the latest entry for `oID 1` because they have no entries since `2014-09-22` - but I need to omit all other data, even though `oID 2` had an entry 18 months ago if they had had one since. How can I accomplish this?

Additionally I need to return any patient with *no* entries:

```
oID   Date          Crea
1     2014-09-22    153
1     2012-10-15    365
2     2014-08-02    212
2     2015-02-18    245
3     2016-03-19    438
4                   514
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
select ifnull(date_column , 'No visit')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a double anti-pattern:

```
    SELECT e1.*                   /* Select entry.. */
      FROM entry e1

 LEFT JOIN entry e2            /* Find later entries for same oid */
        ON e2.oid  = e1.oid
       AND e2.date > e1.date

 LEFT JOIN entry e3            /* Find entries for same oid within 18 months */
        ON e3.oid = e1.oid
       AND e3.date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 MONTH

     WHERE e2.oid IS NULL      /* e2 doesn't exist */
       AND e3.oid IS NULL      /* e3 doesn't exist */
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36e75/3)

Comment: Work perfectly!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for finding difference between two dates.
Try below query

```
SELECT oID
FROM table_name
WHERE 18 < (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date, date)
            FROM table_name a, table_name b
            WHERE a.oID = b.oID);
```

Comment: Thanks - This is handy for finding the datediff but i only wanted to return patients with no date entry for the last 18 months.  Cheers anyway!